# install node.js on debian

Tags: linux, node.js, debian

How to install node.js on Debian Wheezy

Have followed instructions but it doesn't work

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation

```
# wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.24/node-v0.10.24-linux-x64.tar.gz
# tar -zxf node-v0.10.24-linux-x64.tar.gz && cd node-v0.10.24-linux-x64
# ./configure && make && make install
```

The first two lines turn out well, but when running the third line this error is returned

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

## node.js dir

```
root@dyntest-amd-6000-8gb ~/node-v0.10.24-linux-x64 # ls
bin  ChangeLog  include  lib  LICENSE  README.md  share
root@dyntest-amd-6000-8gb ~/node-v0.10.24-linux-x64 #
```

Comment: You should be in the node.js directory to configure

Comment: I am.. check the second line

Comment: did you try listing contents in the directory?

Comment: Can you please run ls between the second and third lines? It would give you a lot of information.

Comment: have updated quesiton with list of node.js directory

Comment: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.24/node-v0.10.24.tar.gz

Comment: The "source code" in that site is not mean "source code column" http://nodejs.org/download/ LOL!

Comment: You've downloaded a binary archive which has `node` already built. You'll find it in the `bin` directory. Node's source archives aren't named for any particular systems, like `linux-x64`. Just name and version, like the `node-v0.10.24.tar.gz` that damphat linked to.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you downloaded a binary distribution but you are running commands as if you are trying to build from source. You don't need `configure` or `make`. It's already an executable ready to go. Just run `~/node-v0.10.24-linux-x64/bin/node` and the repl should start up.

Comment: thx to @Peter Lyons i get the same error, unfortunately i downloaded Linux Binaries, not the Source Code for self compiling.