# Adding a permanent value to $PATH on Raspbian

Tags: linux, node.js, unix, path, debian

I am quite new to Linux so I'm sorry for my newbie question, 
but for about and hour now I'm trying to add Node.js to $PATH with no luck :(

I've used the following line to add Node

```
PATH=$PATH:node-v0.10.24-linux-arm-armv6j-vfp-hard/bin
```

it worked, but when I logged off the terminal and logged in again, the path disappeared.

Later I tried adding the same line to `.profile` , `.logins.defs` and `.bashrc`.
All didn't work so I removed the line.

Please help me with this!

---

P.S , when I added the line to `.profile` I was able to call Node, but when I changed my directory in order to navigate to a Node project directory, I received the following error:

```
-bash: node-v0.10.24-linux-arm-armv6j-vfp-hard/bin/node: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please see my answer below, regarding the utilization of the $HOME variable in your .profile to set your $PATH properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add an absolute path, not a relative one.  You added this to your path: `node-v0.10.24-linux-arm-armv6j-vfp-hard/bin`.  That's a relative path, not an absolute one (absolute paths start with a `/`).  You can change your line to:

```
PATH=$PATH:DIR/node-v0.10.24-linux-arm-armv6j-vfp-hard/bin
```

where `DIR` is the full path of the directory containing `node-v0.10.24-linux-arm-armv6j-vfp-hard`.

It's probably a good idea for you to read a bit on how this all works - it's not that complicated once you see it explained.  See https://superuser.com/questions/238987/how-does-unix-search-for-executable-files for an example.

Comment: Worked! I added /home/pi to the start of the path and it works like a charm! Thanks allot!

Comment: @BenAvnon Glad to help.  If you feel it (or any other answer) adequately answered your question, please don't forget to mark it as accepted. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Glad this worked, but realize this is a specific solution for just the login name pi.  To make it more generic, please see my answer regarding the utilization of the $HOME variable in .profile.  It provides a way the .profile can simply be copied or this section cut&pasted to other logins that have Node installed - with no editing required.

Answer (score 0):

You have $HOME already set to your home directory.

So you can use this in your .profile:

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME:$HOME/bin:$HOME/node-v0.10.24-linux-arm-ar‌​mv6j-vfp-hard/bin"
```

If you set it as an absolute path you will not be able to copy that .profile to another user who is set up similarly.

I see there is another question that deals with installing node.js on Debian - and must admit I am surprised it is installed per-user.  So if you do the install for another login you might want to copy your .profile to the new login to solve this same issue.  There would be no per-user editing required if you use the $HOME variable like this.  Just a simple copy or cut and paste.

For reference, here is that other question/answer:  [install node.js on debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198936/install-node-js-on-debian)